# T-SQL: Quote syntax in building SQL string

Tags: t-sql, syntax, quotes

I am building a SQL sting, mostly the WHERE clause, on the fly based on parameters passed in and the executing the built string. So in the end it is: EXEC (@strSELECT + @strFROM + @strWHERE + @strORDERBY).

My @strSELECT looks like: SET @strSELECT = 'SELECT DISTINCT FieldA, FIELDB, FIELDC'

This all works so far, but now I added a nested function field to the end of @strSELECT so the whole @strSELECT now looks like: SET @strSELECT = 'SELECT DISTINCT FieldA, FIELDB, FIELDC, UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(MyStringDateField AS DATETIME),6),' ','-')) AS FormattedDate'

I know the new nested function field works because I tested it without concantenation and I also know that the problem is with the single quotes [' ','-'] within the function. Can anyone help me with the correct quote syntax when building the query string? thnx.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make your nested function look like this:

UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(MyStringDateField AS datetime),6),'' '',''-''))

Answer (score 1):

Double up on the quotes inside the string. This works for me and returns "02-MAR-11":

```
DECLARE @strSELECT nvarchar(200)
SET @strSELECT = 'SELECT UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME),6),'' '',''-'')) AS FormattedDate'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @strSELECT
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert a single quote in a T-SQL string you prepend another single quote. Thus your @strSelect statement becomes

```
SET @strSELECT = 'SELECT DISTINCT FieldA, FIELDB, FIELDC, UPPER(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(MyStringDateField AS DATETIME),6),'' '',''-'')) AS FormattedDate'
```

That doesn't mean that this is the right way to do it though. You should try to use parameterized queries wherever possible to avoid sql injection attacks